# Sliding Puzzle Solver using Manhattan Distance heuristic

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

My friend and I have created a [sliding puzzle program](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1360672499). And then we have written a method for Manhattan distance and show MD result after every move. We first thought that the best tile for next move is the one with the least MD result. And the problem is that we sometimes get same Manhattan distance in at least two directions.(left, right, up, down). So we think we need other conditions and algorithm to choose the best move. So please advise us which requirements are needed and what is wrong with the program.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the **state** not the **tile**. You need to consider all MDs for a state and not just one tile. In that case, if you had two states with same MD sum, you can take FIFO approach, but must look for visited states to avoid loops.

Comment: For the best node, we checked these conditions manually using our program. We firstly move all possible states and see MD sums. (1) Choose the state with the least value of MD sum. (2) If the states has same MD sum, we ignored the visited state. But sometimes both these states are not visited node. Please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is your decision in such case :)
In fact you if you properly implement it, you won't see the difference. You just sort the nodes and choose first or last (in case of ascending or descending sort) node. If you have two best nodes, you will choose one of them and maybe in next step you will choose the other. Really it doesn't worth taking your time.